# Can I rotate Aircraft Yaw in any direction while performing a Waypoint mission?

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I am creating an Android app using the DJI Mobile SDK.

Is it possible to rotate Aircraft (Drone) Yaw in any direction while performing WaypointMission?

From the link below, I thought it was impossible to rotate using the VirtualStick feature, but are there other alternatives?

https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/FlightController/DJIFlightController.html?search=stickcon&i=0&#djiflightcontroller_virtualstickcontrolmodecategory_isvirtualstickcontrolmodeavailable_inline

> Indicates whether the virtual stick control interface can be used.
>   Virtual stick mode is only available when all of the follow
>   requirements are met:
>        Virtual stick mode is enabled.
>
> - No waypoint, hotpoint, or follow-me mission is running.
> - FlightOrientationMode is set to AIRCRAFT_HEADING
> - Terrain-follow is disabled if the aircraft supports this feature.
> - Tripod mode is disabled if the aircraft supports this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: no, it's not possible.

The only way to get this working is by making your own waypoint mission, which uses the virtual sticks to move the aircraft towards the destination waypoint and allows the user to control the yaw.

There are two major problems if you decide to try making your own mission:

1. The position of the aircraft is only available in WGS84 coordinates and therefore needs to be converted to cartesian coordinates, e.g. UTM, to measure the distance in meters to the next waypoint and the direction from the aircraft to the waypoint.
2. You need to adjust the velocity in relation to the distance to the next waypoint. Unfortunately you have to include the acceleration and braking distance, which is the most difficult part of the task.

Comment: Thank you. Your comments were also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the gimbal in follow mode and rotate the gimbal, the whole aircraft will rotate with it.
Kind of undocumented dji feature.
It will not rotate if in virtualstick mode, only P and waypoint mode.
I think you best bet is to use that.

The biggest problem with virtualstick is that it's very hard to get smooth operation of the gimbal, if you dont have a drone that support gimbal in FREE mode. If you going to use it for smooth filming I recommend against virtualstick.